# How many increasing subsequences of length k can be made from an increasing sequence of length n.

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example, say you are given the sequence 1,2,3,4 and you want sequences of length 3, the sequences would be (1,2,3), (1,3,4), (2,3,4).

Is there a way I could compute the number of sequences like this.

Comment: There should be ${4\choose 3} = 3$ sequences of length $3$. You are missing $(1,2,4)$.

Comment: @marcelgoh You mean 4, not 3.

Comment: @DonThousand Yes of course, oops!

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem as the number of $k$-element subsets of a set of size $n$, which is counted by binomial coefficients ${n\choose k}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are [$n\choose k$ $k$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). To see why $n\choose k$ is also the number of ordered $k$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ we describe a bijection between the two. First, notice that for each $k$-element subset there is exactly one ordering from smallest to largest, and no two subsets give the same ordered set of size $k$ when ordered, so each subset gives one ordered subset. On the other hand, consider an ordered subset of length $k$, each one of these gives exactly one subset of length $k$ because a subset doesn't care which order you list the elements, they're all the same subset.